# JMeter set number of users in thread group from command line/CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I would like to have my tests parametrized so I could run the very same test with different number of users. I know that I could define some user-variable in my test plan, but I would like a solution which would be more friendly for a regular user (who doesn't know JMeter at all).

I've tried using CSV configuration but it appears that I cannot inject (`${numberOfUsers}`) into thread group. Is there any workaround? Maybe I could pass number of users when running my test from command line?

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but: jmx files are plain text, so you could copy a kind of "template" jmx file and create a working copy with the values set the way you need them

Comment: @Marged Thanks for the effort, I've found simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turned out to be really easy-peasy. Instead of acutal users number I set something like this `${__property(myPropertyName)}` in my thead group in JMeter. Then I run my tests like :

```
jmeter -t path/to/test.jmx -JmyPropertyName=10
```

And the test group would have 10 user.